# typeahead-on-select($item, $model, $label) and scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

How can i access the current scope inside my `typeahead-on-select` function? 
If I use `$scope` it will point to the main scope and not to the current one.

the 'current scope' is inside a list so I don't have any way of going there from the main scope because i don't have it's index.

Thanks